# how to add key of object in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Guys.
I have array like this

```
array = [{name:"A",data:"..."},{name:"B",data:"..."},{name:"C",data:"..."}]
```

And I want to edit this array to

```
array = [ "A":{name:"A",data:"..."},"B":{name:"B",data:"..."},"C":{name:"C",data:"..."}
```

How could I set object key from its own value?

Comment: `array = array.map(elem => ({ [elem.name]: elem }));`

Comment: You can't, because `[ "A":{name:"A",data:"..."} ]` is not a valid array (arrays don't have named keys). You have to construct a new object `{ "A":{name:"A",data:"..."} }`

Comment: are you sure, you want an array with properties?

Comment: shouldn't you create object instead of array?

Comment: Oh, You guys are right. then, I'll create it as object. So much thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting an object, you could take [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) with the mapped key/value pairs

```js
var array = [{ name: "A", data: "..." }, { name: "B", data: "..." }, { name: "C", data: "..." }],
    result = Object.fromEntries(array.map(o => [o.name, o ]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Alternatively you can perform a reduction on the array which for each element adds a key/value pair to the accumulator object : `array.reduce((acc, curr) => { acc[curr.name]=curr; return acc; }, {})`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
console.log(array.map(el => ({[el.name]: el})));
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript array doesn't work that way. An array's index value can only have an increasing numeric indexes([0, 1, ..., n]). If you wan't to create such list you can create the object instead of an array.

```js
const array = [{name:"A",data:"..."},{name:"B",data:"..."},{name:"C",data:"..."}];
const newList = {};

array.forEach(obj => {
    newList[obj.name] = obj;
});

console.log({ newList });
```

In this way you can create the object out of array. You can then loop the object's keys like in arrray using:

```
Object.keys(newList).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(newList[key]);
})
```

. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this.

```js
var arr = [{name:"A",data:"..."},{name:"B",data:"..."},{name:"C",data:"..."}]

var output = arr.map(elem => ({[elem.name]: elem}))

console.log(output)
```